# Tools Similar to VSCmdShell?

Tags: visual-studio

I really like [VS Command Shell](http://vscmdshell.codeplex.com/), but it hasn't been updated in a long time and still has various bugs. Are there other similar tools out there?

The VSCmdShell source code is available, but I'd rather not start another side project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NuGet](http://nuget.codeplex.com/) comes with a complete [powershell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) environment.

See [here](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console) on setting up the powershell profile for NuGet.